# Number of ways of getting valid change

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A movie theater charges $50$ Rupees for a ticket.

The cashier starts out with no change, and each change customer pays with a Rupees $50$ note or Rupees $100$ note (& gets change).

Clearly, the cashier will be in trouble if there are too many customers with $100$ rupees note.

It turns out that there are $2n$ customers, and cashier never had to turn them away, but after dealing with last customer, there were no $50$ rupees note left in cash register. Let $w_n$ denote the number of different ways this could have happened.

Find $w_n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: As each customer comes to the cashier, write down a left parenthesis if he pays with a $50$ rupee note and a right parenthesis if he pays with a $100$ rupee note. At the end you will have a string of $2n$ parentheses.

- Show that exactly $n$ of the customers paid with a $50$ rupee note, so that the string has $n$ left and $n$ right parentheses.
- Show that as you read the string of parentheses from left to right, you have always seen at least as many left parentheses as right parentheses. For example, if $n=3$, you might see `(()())` or `()()()`, but you cannot see `())(()` or `)((())`.

Now look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) on Catalan numbers, especially the part on Dyck words in [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics).

Comment: Thanks , your post was indeed usefull including links :) i can show both points easily but i am having difficulties in calculations , how can we calculate possible sequences like you showed using parenthesis ?
It would be very useful @Brian M.Scott if you could directly tell the answer/explanation as tomorrow is itself my olympiad :)

Comment: So is the answer (2n)!/((n+1)!n! ? But how can we prove that ?

Comment: @Maggi: The article actually has a proof, though you have to modify it slightly. Look at [this proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof), but think of each $\to$ step as a `(` and each $\uparrow$ step as a `)`. The legitimate parenthesis strings correspond to the lattice paths that do not cross the diagonal.

Comment: Thanks a lot Proffessor Brian M.Scott :D
I loved combinatorcs a lot but this sector was totally unexplored by me , your links and application of Catalan nos. has really given me more approaches and techniques ! Thanks a looooot :D

Comment: @Maggi: You’re welcome!